# How to convert a string of dates to a date object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I'm doing [a chatbot to book rooms](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot). I've created a function to check if the room asked is free while looking in the database. At some point I try to convert the entry starting and ending meeting hour to a tupple with `from_pendulum_to_tupple(day_startinghour)` with `day_startinghour` beeing for instance `2019-04-18T14:00:00+00:00`

```
    def from_pendulum_to_tupple(date):
        print("date: ")
        print(date)
        print("type : " + str(type(date)))
        year = date.year
        month = date.month
        day = date.day
        hour = date.hour
        minute = date.minute
        return (year, month, day, hour, minute)
```

Yet I have an AttributeError: `str` object has no attribute `year`. Indeed, the error message is:

> File
>   "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\actions.py",
>   line 43, in run
>               booking_answer = make_a_booking(name_room, day, hour_start, duration)
>             File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\booking.py",
>   line 94, in make_a_booking
>               room_available = is_the_room_available(name_room, day_only, pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_start, 
>           pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_end, cnx)
>             File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\booking.py",
>   line 52, in 
>           is_the_room_available
>               starting_hour_list.append(from_pendulum_to_tupple(start_time))
>             File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\booking.py",
>   line 14, in 
>           from_pendulum_to_tupple
>               year = date.year
>           AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
>           127.0.0.1 - - [2019-04-17 16:42:01] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 412 1.050171

`day_startinghour` was created with `make_a_booking` which takes room, a day and an hour before calling for the above function to know if the room is used on the times we want to book it:

```
def make_a_booking(name_room, day, hour_start, duration):

    print(name_room, day, hour_start, duration)
    # connect to the localhost database
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(password='MySQL.2019', user="root", database="alex")

    #day_only : get the parsed date
    day_only = str(dateparser.parse(day).date())

    # parse the hour in string inputed by the user and convert it the a pendulum object
    hour_start_parsed = dateutil.parser.parse(hour_start, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
    pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_start = pendulum.parse(str(day_only) + " " + hour_start, strict=False)

    # convert the duration in string inputed by the user and to seconds then in minutes
    duration_in_seconds = convert_time(duration)
    duration_in_minutes = duration_in_seconds / 60

    # add the duration_in_minutes to the starting hour to get the hour start pendulum object
    pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_end = pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_start.add(minutes = duration_in_minutes)
    #print(pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_end)

    # check if the room is available
    room_available = is_the_room_available(name_room, day_only, pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_start, pendulum_combined_day_and_hour_end, cnx)
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example instead? Do you intend to convert the string date to a date object? If so, maybe provide us a sample list of string dates?

Comment: Its `str`. Just turn it into a date using `datetime.strptime(...)`.

Comment: `print("type : " + str(type(date)))` what are you even doing?

Comment: `print(type(date))` and what do you get?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you really shouldn't be storing passwords, etc. for databases in your source code files and then pushing them to github...

Answer (score 0):

Using [`dparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

def from_pendulum_to_tupple(date):
    print("date: {}".format(date))
    date = dparser.parse(date,fuzzy=True)
    year = date.year
    month = date.month
    day = date.day
    hour = date.hour
    minute = date.minute
    return (year, month, day, hour, minute)

s = '2019-04-18T14:00:00+00:00'
print(from_pendulum_to_tupple(s))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
date: 2019-04-18T14:00:00+00:00
(2019, 4, 18, 14, 0)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Yet I have the following error while installing `dparser`: `error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: Many thinks ! Yet I think your link solve the problem for Ubuntu user and I have Windows 10